# how to dismiss a UIPickerView in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, uitouch

In my app, i have pickerviews in my add contact page. I have given the following 'touchesBegan' method. But it dismisses the picker even when i click on a value to set. For example, if i click 'homephone' from preferred phone picker, the picker gets dismissed instead of setting the value. i need the picker to be dismissed only if i click outside the picker. Can anyone help me in fixing this.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 [self.AddView endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([touch view] != pickerview)
     [self.AddView endEditing:YES];
}
```

this will be used to endedit when the touch is outside the picker view

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Or You can put a bigger button under the PickerView, make it color clear custom and dimension full screen, then use the dismiss inside a `(IBAction)` and when you tap outside the picker your view is dismissed

```
- (IBAction)buttonClear:(id)sender {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: put a bigger button under the PickerView, make it color clear custom and dimension full screen, then use the dismiss inside a (IBAction) and when you tap outside the picker your view is dismissed ;) i add a code on my post

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *single_tap_recognizer;

    single_tap_recognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                              initWithTarget : self.view
                              action         : @selector(upper_button_view_tapped)]
                             autorelease];

    [single_tap_recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired : 1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer : single_tap_recognizer];

-(void)upper_button_view_tapped
{
 [self .view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Hope it help You